# apache shiro: how to set the authenticationStrategy using spring applicationcontext?

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, web, shiro, realm

I've been struggling with authenticationStrategy settings with shiro 1.2.1 in a spring based web application. I have 2 realms. One authenticates against `database` and one against ldap. both `realms` are working fine just that i wanted a `FirstSuccessfulStrategy` but it seems both realms are still being called. here is my security-application-context:

```
<bean id="passwordService" class="org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.DefaultPasswordService">
    <property name="hashService" ref="hashService" />

</bean>

<bean id="hashService" class="org.apache.shiro.crypto.hash.DefaultHashService">
    <property name="hashAlgorithmName" value="SHA-512" />
    <property name="hashIterations" value="500000" />
</bean>


<bean id="SaltedSha512JPARealm" class="bla.bla.webapp.security.SaltedSha512JPARealm">
    <property name="credentialsMatcher">
        <bean class="org.apache.shiro.authc.credential.PasswordMatcher">
            <property name="passwordService" ref="passwordService"/>
        </bean>
    </property>

</bean>


<bean id="ldapContextFactory" class="org.apache.shiro.realm.ldap.JndiLdapContextFactory">
    <property name="url" value="${user.ldap.connection.url}"/>
    <property name="authenticationMechanism" value="${user.ldap.connection.auth_mecanism}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="ldapRealm" class="bla.bla.webapp.security.LDAPRealm">
    <property name="userDnTemplate" value="${user.ldap.connection.userDnTemplate}"/>
    <property name="contextFactory" ref="ldapContextFactory" />

</bean>

<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager" depends-on="roleRepository,roleRightRepository,rightRepository,userRepository">

    <property name="realms">
        <list>
            <ref local="ldapRealm"/>
            <ref local="SaltedSha512JPARealm"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticator.authenticationStrategy">
        <bean class="org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.FirstSuccessfulStrategy"/>
    </property>

</bean>
```

is there anything there that i am not doing well?

Answer (score 2):

`FirstSuccessfulStrategy` means that your authenticator will try all your realms to authenticate user until the first successful. Your realms was configured in order: `ldapRealm`, `SaltedSha512JPARealm`. So if `lapRealm` will fail authenticator will try second one. To solve this you can try to configure the most successful or the quickest realm to be first, e.g. you can change your realms order to be `SaltedSha512JPARealm`, `ldapRealm`:

```
<bean id="securityManager" class="org.apache.shiro.web.mgt.DefaultWebSecurityManager" depends-on="roleRepository,roleRightRepository,rightRepository,userRepository">

    <property name="realms">
        <list>
            <ref local="SaltedSha512JPARealm"/>
            <ref local="ldapRealm"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="authenticator.authenticationStrategy">
        <bean class="org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.FirstSuccessfulStrategy"/>
    </property>

</bean>
```

But you should understand that for this configuration if `SaltedSha512JPARealm` will fail, authenticator will try `ldapRealm`.

Or you can try to use different token classes for this realms. But it will work only if you have different authentication entry points for each of them.

**UPD**

It seems that `ModularRealmAuthenticator` is designed so that it will always try to authenticate user by all realms. `FirstSuccessfulStrategy` can affect only on authentication result. It will return first successful `AuthenticationInfo`. To achieve your goal you need to override `ModularRealmAuthenticator#doMultiRealmAuthentication` method. It can look like this:

```
protected AuthenticationInfo doMultiRealmAuthentication(Collection<Realm> realms, AuthenticationToken token) {
    AuthenticationStrategy strategy = getAuthenticationStrategy();
    AuthenticationInfo aggregate = strategy.beforeAllAttempts(realms, token);
    if (log.isTraceEnabled()) {
        log.trace("Iterating through {} realms for PAM authentication", realms.size());
    }
    for (Realm realm : realms) {
        aggregate = strategy.beforeAttempt(realm, token, aggregate);
        if (realm.supports(token)) {
            log.trace("Attempting to authenticate token [{}] using realm [{}]", token, realm);
            AuthenticationInfo info = null;
            Throwable t = null;
            try {
                info = realm.getAuthenticationInfo(token);
            } catch (Throwable throwable) {
                t = throwable;
                if (log.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    String msg = "Realm [" + realm + "] threw an exception during a multi-realm authentication attempt:";
                    log.debug(msg, t);
                }
            }
            aggregate = strategy.afterAttempt(realm, token, info, aggregate, t);
            // dirty dirty hack
            if (aggregate != null && !CollectionUtils.isEmpty(aggregate.getPrincipals())) {
                return aggregate;
            }
            // end dirty dirty hack
        } else {
            log.debug("Realm [{}] does not support token {}.  Skipping realm.", realm, token);
        }
    }
    aggregate = strategy.afterAllAttempts(token, aggregate);
    return aggregate;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. My problem is that even after a successful authentication against `stuart ldap server`(http://blog.stuartlewis.com/2008/07/07/test-ldap-service/) , it tries to authenticate against database using `SaltedSha512JPARealm`. That's why i though something is wrong with my configuration. knowing ldapRealm was added first it should not happen right?

Comment: You are right. It seems that `ModularRealmAuthenticator` is designed so that it will always try to authenticate user by all realms. Just updated answer.

Comment: Hi sorry for the late response. i've tried using different token and create them based on the combobox i put on the UI just like MS windows login for switching domain.That's my quick fix for now. I will try this solution in next iteration, i'm caught by deadline. so that fix works fine for the UI guy and management.

Answer (score 0):

```
<property name="authenticator.authenticationStrategy">
    <bean class="org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.FirstSuccessfulStrategy"/>
</property>
```

the above definition is wrong. Define it as follows

```
<property name="authenticator.authenticationStrategy" ref="authcStrategy"/>
```

And define the below bean definition separately

```
<bean id="authcStrategy"     class="org.apache.shiro.authc.pam.FirstSuccessfulStrategy"/>
```

Then it will work as expected